# How to keep the decimal part in a value?

Tags: vb.net

The res1 is displaying the number as integer,how can i get it to display the resulted number and keeping the decimal part?

P.s this method is being called from another class so the numbers are given from there but still same result.

```
Public Sub max(num1, num2)
    If (num1 > num2) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Max: " & num1)
    Else : MessageBox.Show("Max: " & num2)
    End If

End Sub
Public Sub min(num1, num2)
    If (num1 < num2) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Min: " & num1)
    Else : MessageBox.Show("Min: " & num2)
    End If

End Sub
Public Sub avg(num1, num2)
    res1 = (num1 + +num2) \ 2
    MessageBox.Show("Average: " & res1)
End Sub
```

I tried adding 'Cdec' and 'Cdbl' but still the average is being displayed as Integer.
I used to place something like this in c language (res=(float)num1+num2) and it worked but what's the alternative of that in vb.net?

Comment: turn on Option Strict - ` \ ` is integer division, so you get integers

Comment: well i guess i should thank you, changing '\' to '/' solved the problem....i was searching all over the threads to see what i did wrong but couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Public Sub avg(num1 As Decimal, num2 As Decimal)
        Dim res1 As Decimal
        res1 = (num1 + +num2) / 2d

        MessageBox.Show("Average: " & res1)
   End Sub
```

call it

```
 avg(10D, 5.5D)
```

[Decimal Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx)

Comment: it turned out that all what i had to do was turn '\' to '/'...your solution is anextra useful one too so thanks!

Comment: @xTMx yes, but good practice is to always convert data to proper data type. Like here sending  avg(10D, 5.5D) ,  "D" = decimal. And always have option strict on.. keep working

Comment: The numbers are being sent by the user through a textbox, so i dunno if it'll work like that,but i'm sure i'll remember your advice . I just started learning vb couple of weeks ago, Fun and interesting language i would say.